# Purpose of using the has-validation-callback

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Please pardon my question - a newbie to HTML and JavaScript.

I have see HTML form TAG use the "has-validation-callback" class .

What is it used for !

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What is `class` in HTML for you by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Classes have no predefined meaning in HTML.

It could be used by some JavaScript embedded in the page. It could be used by CSS. It could be used by some server-side code for some automated process of the page unrelated to a browser.